# ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_4

Tags: python, keras

i have an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_4 to have shape (None, 2) but got array with shape (12956, 1)
```

When i run this script.

```
def image_text_model(image_features, text_features, n_classes):
    # fine-tune the last layer
    image_features = Input(shape=image_features.shape[1:], dtype='float32')

    n_text_features = text_features.shape[1]
    text_features = Input(shape=text_features.shape[1:], dtype='float32')

    # text model
    x_text = Dense(256, activation='elu', kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-5))(text_features)
    x_text = Dropout(0.5)(x_text)

    # image model
    x_img = Dense(256, activation='elu')(image_features)
    x_img = Dropout(0.5)(x_img)
    x_img = Dense(256, activation='elu')(x_img)
    x_img = Dropout(0.5)(x_img)

    merged = concatenate([x_img, x_text])
    predictions = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')(merged)

    model = Model(inputs=[image_features, text_features], outputs=[predictions])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model



# dev
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_dir, 'amazon_products_dev.csv'))
dev_image_list = df['image_file'].values
dev_text = df['title'].values.tolist()
dev_categories = df['product_category'].values

# encode labels (binary labels)
encoder = LabelBinarizer()
train_labels = encoder.fit_transform(train_categories)
dev_labels = encoder.transform(dev_categories)

# get features from a pre-trained resnet model
vec = ResNetVectorizer(batch_size=500,
                       image_dir=image_dir,
                       use_cache=True,
                       cache_dir=cache_dir)
train_image_features = vec.transform(train_image_list)
dev_image_features = vec.transform(dev_image_list)


# get text features
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), stop_words='english', max_features=5000)
train_text_features = tfidf.fit_transform(train_text)
dev_text_features = tfidf.transform(dev_text).toarray()

# fine-tune the last layer
n_classes = encoder.classes_.shape[0]
model = image_text_model(train_image_features, train_text_features, n_classes)


data_gen = sparse_batch_generator(train_image_features, train_text_features, train_labels, shuffle=True)
steps_per_epoch = int(np.ceil(train_image_features.shape[0]/32.))
model.fit_generator(data_gen,
                    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                    epochs=50,
validation_data=[[dev_image_features, dev_text_features], dev_labels])
```

I See this topic : [ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_4 to have shape (None, 4) but got array with shape (13252, 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235611/valueerror-error-when-checking-model-target-expected-dense-4-to-have-shape-no)
But i don't know how can use it into my script.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Hard to tell, I'm not sure why your using a fit generator that takes a variable, and not a generators function name. We would need to see the generator function also

Answer (score 0):

Currently you must only have two classes as you output is expecting `(None, 2)`. However, when working with two classes, you matrix structure can either be

```
[[0,1],
 [1,0],
 [1,0]]
```

or

```
[[0],
 [1],
 [1]]
```

Sklearns `LabelBinarizer` converts a matrix with two classes into a column of zeros and one's. 0 for class one and 1 for class two. So your output layer should just be

```
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged)
```